# not showing correct updates while commit with github for windows

Tags: github-for-windows

I have installed the github for windows http://windows.github.com/.

Also already clone a repository into my local drive. I created a branch, and make some update on one file, e.g: index.html. When I commit with github for windows. Github seems to treat it as whole file update (whole line becomes red), instead of showing the modification which I've already made. But this will not happen while I commit with command line.

Does anyone seems ever to have same problem with me? Please tell me what should I do to make the git didn't treat my files as a whole update?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Rustam Safin about the CRLF line endings, recently I found this solution was helpful.

https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

I have tried it, and it's resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you write files in Windows, they have a CRLF line endings. Lines with \n and \r\n line endings are different for Git. Please check your editor's and Github for Windows preferences. They can convert CRLF<->LF automatically.